# Flask: How can I use `app` variable in the entire project?

Tags: python, flask

I would like to know how to use `app` variable in any files in my project.

Tutorial: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/tutorial/
Code to create a variable `app`: [https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/2.3.3/examples/tutorial/flaskr/**init**.py](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/2.3.3/examples/tutorial/flaskr/__init__.py)

I tried this tutorial above. In this tutorial, `app = Flask(__name__)` is written in `__init__.py`

```
def create_app(test_config=None):
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    
    #### DO SOMETHING

    return app
```

The problem is `__init__.py` does not expose `app` variable, so I cannot use `app` (such as `@app.route` and `app.logger`) in other files.

What is the right way to make `app` available in other files?

##### Environment

- Python 3.11.4
- Flask 2.3.3

Answer (score 1):

To say, In Flask, you can make the `app` variable available in other files by using a technique called "**Application Factories.**" https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/patterns/appfactories/

1. Create the Application Factory:

In your `__init__.py` file, define the application factory function, as you've already done:

```
from flask import Flask

def create_app(test_config=None):
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)

    # Configure your app here if needed

    return app
```

Make sure to create the app instance within this function and return it.

2. Access app in Other Files:

To access the `app` instance in other files, you need to import it using the following pattern:

```
from flask import current_app

# You can now use current_app to access the app instance
current_app.route('/')
current_app.logger.debug('Debug message')
```

Instead of directly importing the app instance, you should import `current_app` from `flask`.

`current_app` is a proxy to the actual app instance, and it allows you to access the application context, which is necessary for routing, logging, and other Flask features. https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/api/#flask.current_app

Using `current_app`:

In your other files (e.g., views, models), you can use current_app just like you would use app.

For example, you can define `routes`, `configure extensions`, or `log messages`:

from flask import current_app

```
@current_app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello, World!'

# Using the logger
current_app.logger.debug('Debug message')
```

You can access the `app` instance created in your `application factory` throughout your Flask project without exposing the app variable directly.

Using `current_app` ensures that you're working within the correct application context, which is crucial for a `Flask application`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm getting the idea. It seems `current_app` sometimes requires `with app.app_context()`. Do I still need `app`?